# How to use lens set function with Maybe?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, option-type, lenses

I have a tuple `x` and a `Maybe` value `y`

```
x = (1,1)
y = Just 2
```

I can do this

```
z = maybe x (\v -> x & _1 .~ v) y
```

Or I can create my own operator

```
(.~?) x y =  x %~ (\v -> fromMaybe v y)

z = x & _1 .~? y
```

But if `lens` doesn't have such operator, maybe I don't need it?

So, how to use `lens` `set` function with `Maybe`?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here - do you want a function `(a,b) -> Maybe a -> (a,a)` or a function `(a,b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe (a,b)`?

Comment: `(a,b) -> Maybe a -> (a,a)`, but `(a,b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe (a,b)` also would be interesting

Comment: Did you mean `(\v -> x & _1 .~ v)` instead?

Comment: could you please make a full example of input & output; also I'd recommend to have a look at prisms `Maybe` it is just the thing you are looking for.

Comment: There is already full example. I have a tuple `(1,2)` and I have an input `Maybe Int`. What is the right way to update this tuple with this input using `lens`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want

```
maybeSetFst :: (a, b) -> Maybe a -> (a, b)
```

which will update the first field if given an update value and will leave it alone otherwise. I think the first implementation you give is very good, but you can give it a more general type:

```
maybeSetFst :: Field1 s s a a => s -> Maybe a -> s
```

If you don't want that generality, you can skip the lenses and write (using `TupleSections`)

```
maybeSetFst p@(_,b) = maybe p (,b)
```

Another option is to apply `maybe` to get the update function:

```
maybeSetFst p m = maybe id (_1 .~) m p
```

which can be written

```
maybeSetFst = flip $ maybe id (_1 .~)
```

for point-free silliness.